# Body Parser not reading data from form

Tags: javascript, json, express, pug, body-parser

I can't seem to figure out what the hell i'm doing wrong here. I'm rendering a form with a GET request and trying to parse the information into a POST request and render it as a JSON.

```
app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  res.render('searchForm')
})

app.post('/results', (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body);
})
```

This is what my form looks like (it's a pug/jade file):

```
extends layout

block content

  div.container  
    h1 This is the events page
    form(action="/results" method="POST")
      label(for="address") Search!
      br
      input(type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address")
      br
      br
      input(type="submit" value="Search   " class="btn btn-primary")
```

When console.logging `req.body` to the server, I get `undefined` and when I send it to the client I get nothing, and nothing shows on the console either. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo when using the module:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```